# Are custom buttons possible in an alert box?

Tags: javascript, confirm

Hi I have been looking to create custom buttons in an alert box I would like them to say Go and Cancel instead of OK and cancel

```
onClick="if(confirm('Would you like to continue?'))
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no cross-browser support for opening a confirmation dialog that is not the default OK/Cancel pair, but you can build them with JavaScript such as [jQuery Alert Dialogs](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/), [jQuery impromptu](http://www.trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php), [Mootools LightFace](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox) and many more.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, as far I know. The button caption are not customizable by design.

It is needed to avoid possible fraud (think what can happen if you switch the caption of
confirm and cancel buttons).

Comment: Actually, you are the one who asks the question so instead of switching buttons you might rephrase your question as well. Not to mention that using if(!confirm('Would you like to continue?')) instead of if(confirm('Would you like to continue?')) would do the same as changing the buttons.

Comment: @Zed: He wants to change the text label of the buttons.

Comment: @jnpcl: Yes. And I said why not being able to do that doesn't make fraud impossible. See the answer on which I'm commenting.

Comment: @Zed: But if the script was coded like that, then somebody who DID want to continue would get the Cancel case.

Comment: Clarification: in "you are the one who asks the question" by "you" I mean the programmer who writes JavaScript and by "question" I mean the question that is an argument to confirm() - if that was not clear enough.

Comment: @jnpcl: And that is exactly my point. If you want to "switch the caption of confirm and cancel buttons" to fool the user than you might negate the return value just as well. The point is that it doesn't avoid possible fraud.

Comment: @Zed: Ahh, I see now. You were saying: "You can still trick the user without changing labels."

Answer (score 1):

With this its possible,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28812/Custom-Alert-Boxes-using-JavaScript-and-the-DOM