# How to replace default alert box with custom alert box

Tags: javascript, alert

I tried to make one exam using html forms which would find the incorrect answer and will write   the correct answer using alert box

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046754/are-custom-buttons-possible-in-an-alert-box

Comment: check out fancybox.  Or if you want to use bootstrap it has built in modals.

Comment: Remember to post what you have done until now, because we cannot guess your reasoning. Please read this section to improve your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Use one of them.................

http://www.trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox